# Minimizing error of intercept estimate for a given N

Tags: regression, estimation, intercept

Suppose you know that $y = a + bx + \epsilon$ is your generating process, where $\epsilon$ is $N(0, \sigma^2)$, but you don't know the parameters $a, b, \sigma$.

You have a limited number of trials to conduct, choosing $x$ and measuring $y$. Your goal is to estimate $a$.

Is it always the case that you should conduct all your trials with $x = 0$ (and so your estimate for $a$ will just be the average of the measured $y$'s)?

The motivation for this question is a discussion of regression parameter estimation in Freedman's *Statistical Models*. A quick and dirty simulation suggests that the answer is yes, you're better off choosing $x = 0$ for all trials, especially if there's a measurement error associated with non-zero values of $x$ (but no error for $x = 0$).

Comment: (+1) In many practical cases it's impossible or meaningless to set $x=0$ (what if $x$ is a person's height?).  Another issue to contemplate is the meaning of "should," because it implies some unstated objectives.  For instance, many would think it foolhardy to design an experiment that did not yield data that permit the model to be checked.  That would imply a need to use at least two distinct settings of $x$, even when the main objective is accurate estimation of $a$.  These considerations really amount to wondering whether you view this as a purely mathematical exercise or a practical one.

Comment: Good points @whuber! The context in Freedman's text is Hooke's law relating length of a spring to applied force. There, the model corresponds to a (known) physical law, and the error comes from measuring $y$. Measuring the spring in a relaxed state would be $x = 0$, but I suppose that for any non-zero $x$, there'll be some measurement error associated with the weight/force.

Comment: As long as I'm making tangential points, a particularly subtle one is that sometimes the value $x=0$ is special even when it's possible.  There can be a sharp difference between the limiting value of $y$ as $x$ approaches zero and the value of $y$ right at zero.  That gives "$a$" two distinct meanings: one is its role in the model for non-zero $x$ and the other is the expectation of $y$ when $x=0$. If the purpose in estimating $a$ is to help with later applications when $x\ne 0$, then maybe $a$ would be best estimated by keeping the experimental values of $x$ within intended ranges.